# Dyanamically change href of javascript youtube player using jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, dynamic, youtube

```
    <a id="bgndVideo" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mAf6zKRb1wI" 
class="movie {opacity:.8, isBgndMovie:{width:'window',mute:false}, o
ptimizeDisplay:true, showControls:true, ratio:'4/3', loop: true}">vito 
acconci theme song 1973</a>
```

Above is the html that I have used within my document to embed the javascript chromeless youtube player as a background. I got the code from http://pupunzi.com/mb.components/mb.YTPlayer/demo/demo_background.html

The href controls the video that is set as a background I want to dynamically change the href of the above html with a constant.

What I have tried:

```
var DATA = VideoID

$("bgndVideo").attr("href", DATA)
```

this did not work, nor did

```
document.getElementById("bgndVideo").href=DATA;
```

this did not work either. Any suggestions? It might be a good idea to view source on the example site above to get a better idea of what I mean, I find it hard to articulate my problems properly!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the movie by changing the `href`. It has already been used and is no longer available to the player as soon as you initialize the player. If you change the URL before initial, then yes, but that is likely not what you want.

Take a look here:

https://github.com/pupunzi/jquery.mb.YTPlayer/wiki

> $.fn.changeMovie(URL, opt)
>
> This method let you change the video of the specified player passing a new parameter object to set specific properties.

Here is my take on your code

```
$('#bgndVideo').changeMovie('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+DATA, {opacity:.4, ratio:'16/9'});
```

I however think you might want this:

```
var movies = [
  {"id":"mAf6zKRb1wI","title":"Vito Acconci theme song 1973 -- part 1"},
  {"id":"2MxhNdyADEU","title":"Vito Acconci theme song 1973 -- part 2"},
  {"id":"xOsWwpzqlZw","title":"Vito Acconci theme song 1973 -- part 3"}
]; // note no comma after the last

$(function() {
  $.each(movies,function() {
    $("#container").append('<button data-id="'+
      $(this).id+'" class="buttons">'+
      $(this).title+'</button>');
  });
  $(".buttons").on("click", function() {
    $("#bgndVideo").changeMovie("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+
     $(this).data("id"), {opacity:.4, ratio:"16/9"});
  });
});
```

Comment: You have answered how to change the url to a set url. The question was how can I change the url to a variable.